Eigenvalues of certain matrices
We write $R(\theta)=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}\cos(2\pi\theta)&\sin(2\pi\theta)\\ -\sin(2\pi\theta)&\cos(2\pi\theta)\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ for any $\theta\in\mathbb R$.
Let $d,m,n,r$ be a positive integers satisfying $r^d\equiv 1\pmod m$.
We define the $2d\times2d$-matrices $A$ and $B$ by
$$
A=
\begin{pmatrix}
R(\tfrac1m)\\
&R(\tfrac{r}{m})\\
&&R(\tfrac{r^2}{m})\\
&&&\ddots\\
&&&&R(\tfrac{r^{d-1}}{m})
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and
$$
B=
\begin{pmatrix}
0&I_2\\
&0&I_2\\
&&\ddots&\ddots\\
&&&0&I_2\\
R(\tfrac{d}{n})&&&&0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
(Here $I_2$ stands for the $2\times 2$ identity matrix.)
One can easily check that $A^m=B^n=I_{2d}$.
Question:
What are the eigenvalues of $A^aB^b$ for $0\leq a<m$ and $0\leq b<n$?
With the help of a computer, I know the answer for several cases when $d=2,3,4$.
However, I have no idea how to work with an arbitrary $d$.
What kind of tools can I use?
Are there any reason to hope that this can be calculated?
These matrices arise trying to compute the Laplace spectrum of spherical space forms with fundamental groups of Type I.
Under some further conditions, the group $\Gamma$ generated by $A$ and $B$ is of Type I, and $S^{2d-1}/\Gamma$ is the corresponding spherical space form.

Isn't this just character theory of metacyclic groups? Or have I misunderstood something?

It might be... I will google it. Thanks for the keywords.

These are some interesting matrices. I did not find that $B^n=I_{2d}$ always, though this was true when $n$ was a multiple of $d$.
The case of $r=1$ seemed different from the more general case $r>1$ and I did not consider it in detail since it may not be of interest.
Preliminaries
The matrices $R(\theta ),~\theta \in \mathbb{R}$ comprise a family of
mutually commuting orthogonal matrices with common eigenvectors. The unitary
matrix $U$ with columns of the normalized eigenvectors can be used to
diagonalize any $R(\theta )$, $
R(\theta )=U\Lambda U^{\ast },$ $
\Lambda =U^{\ast }R(\theta )U$, where
$$
\Lambda =
\begin{bmatrix}
\exp (+2\pi i\theta ) & 0 \\ 
0 & \exp (-2\pi i\theta )
\end{bmatrix}
,~U=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\begin{bmatrix}
-i & i \\ 
1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\text{.}
$$
Therefore any product of the $2\times 2$ blocks here can be easily
diagonalized,
$$U^{\ast }R(\theta )R(\theta ^{\prime })U=U^{\ast }R(\theta
)UU^{\ast }R(\theta ^{\prime })U=\Lambda \Lambda ^{\prime }$$, which
significantly simplifies the problem.
Let $R_{m}=R(1/m)$, then the powers $R_{m}^{k}=R(k/m)$ have eigenvalues $
\exp (\pm 2\pi ik/m)$. $R_{m}^{k}$ is equal to $I_{2}$ when $k=m$, i.e., the
sequence $R_{m}^{k},~k=0,1,\ldots $has period $m$. More generally the
sequence $\left( R_{m}^{j}\right) ^{k},~k=0,1,\ldots $ has period $\operatorname{lcm}
(j,m)/j\leq m$.
Eigenvalues of $A^{a}$
The eigenvalues of $A$ are the union of the eigenvalues of its blocks, and
therefore are $\exp (\pm 2\pi ir^{k}/m),k=0,\ldots ,d-1$. The eigenvalues of
$A^{a}$ are $\exp (\pm 2\pi ir^{k}a/m),k=0,\ldots ,d-1,$ and these are all
unity for $a=m$, i.e., $A^{m}=I_{2d}$ and the sequence of the $A^{a}$ has
period $m$. Since the first block of $A$ is $R_{m}$ with period $m$, there
cannot be a shorter period for the $A^{a}$.
Period of $B^{b}$
The situation for $B$ is more complicated. The block $R_{n}^{d}$ has period $
p:=\operatorname{lcm}(d,n)/d\leq n$, but the block structure is not diagonal and has
its own period. It is instructive to write the first few matrices in the
sequence $B^{b},b=0,1,\ldots $ for the case $d=4$. ($R_{n}^{d}$ is here
abbrieviated as $R$ and $I_{2}$ as $I$.)
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
I & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & I & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & I & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & I%
\end{bmatrix}%
,~
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & I & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & I & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & I \\ 
R & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
,~
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & I & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & I \\ 
R & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & R & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
,~
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & I \\ 
R & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & R & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & R & 0
\end{bmatrix}
,
$$
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
R & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & R & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & R & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & R
\end{bmatrix}
,~%
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & R & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & R & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & R \\ 
R^{2} & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
,~%
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & R & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & R \\ 
R^{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & R^{2} & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
,\ldots 
$$
The zero/non-zero block structure has periodicity $d$: $B$ becomes block
diagonal when $b$ is a multiple of $d$. Each such quasi-period gains an
additional factor of $D_{R}=\operatorname{diag}(R,R,\ldots )$ and the true
period occurs when $D_{R}^{p}=I_{2d}$ and $R^{p}=I$. That is, the period of $
B^{b}$ will be $\operatorname{lcm}(p,d)$. If $n$ is a multiple of $d$ then $
B^{n}=I_{2d}$
Eigenvalues of $B^{b}$
The matrix $B$ is in block companion matrix form, with the $2\times 2$
blocks along the last row corresponding to the negated coefficients of the
characteristic matrix polynomial $I_{2}x^{d}-R_{n}^{d}$ .Applying the
unitary similarity with $U$ gives $I_{2}x^{d}-\operatorname{diag}(\rho ,\overline{
\rho })$, where $\rho $ and $\overline{\rho }$ are the eigenvalues of $
R_{n}^{d}$. Taking the determinant gives $(x^{d}-\rho )(x^{d}-\overline{\rho 
})=0$ and solving for $x$ gives the $2d$ eigenvalues for $B,$ namely $\omega
^{k}\rho ^{1/d}$ and $\omega ^{k}\overline{\rho }^{1/d}$, $k=0,\ldots ,d-1$
where $\omega $ is the principal $d$th root of unity. Explicitly, these are $
\exp (2\pi ik/d)\exp (\pm 2\pi i/n),$ $k=0,\ldots ,d-1$. It follows that the
eigenvalues of $B^{b}$ are $\exp (2\pi ikb/d)\exp (\pm 2\pi ib/n),$ $
k=0,\ldots ,d-1$. For the case $b\operatorname{mod}d=0,$ the matrices $B^{b}$ are
block diagonal and the first factor simplifies to $1$; the eigenvalues are
then $d$ copies of a complex-conjugate pair.
Eigenvalues of $A^{a}B^{b}$
We first show that the $2d\times 2d$ problem splits into two $d\times d$
problems. Note that $B^{b}$ has one block in each row and column, and
premultiplying by the block diagonal $A^{a}$ multiplies the block in the $i$%
th pair of rows of $B^{b}$ by the $i$th block of $A^{a}$, preserving the
block structure. Performing the similarity $U_{2d}^{\ast }A^{a}B^{b}U_{2d}$
with $U_{2d}=\operatorname{diag}(U,U,\ldots )$ diagonalizes all the blocks, with
the diagonal entries of each block now containing the products of the
respective eigenvalues of the matrix factors in the block.
A permutation
similarity that moves odd rows and columns to the beginning and even rows
and columns to the end generates a block diagonal form with the first $%
d\times d$ block, $W$, having the same structure as $A^{a}B^{b}$ but having
the first eigenvalues from each $2\times 2$ block, and with the second $%
d\times d$ block having the second eigenvalues. Therefore the eigenvalues
of $A^{a}B^{b}$ come in two sets of $d$, with the second being complex
conjugates of the first.
We deal now only with the first $d\times d$ block.
We write $\alpha _{1},\ldots ,\alpha _{d}$ for the first eigenvalues of each
$2\times 2$ block of $A,$ $\lambda _{i}=\alpha _{i}^{a}$ for the first
eigenvalues of the blocks of $A^{a}$, and (as above) $\rho $ for the first
eigenvalue of $R_{n}^{d}$. For example, with $d=4$ and $b=5$ we have
$$
W=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -\alpha _{1}^{a}\rho  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & -\alpha _{2}^{a}\rho  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & -\alpha _{3}^{a}\rho  \\ 
-\alpha _{4}^{a}\rho ^{2} & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
=\operatorname{diag}\left( \lambda _{1},\ldots \lambda _{4}\right) \operatorname{diag}
\left( \rho ,\rho ,\rho ,\rho ^{2}\right) 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where the last matrix is $C_{4}^{5}=C_{4}$, the basic circulant permutation
matrix of order $4$, corresponding to the permutation $\sigma =(1234)$. In
the common case, as here, where the permutation has only one cycle, the
characteristic polynomial $\left\vert xI_{d}-W\right\vert $ has only one
term other than $x^{d}$, which arises from the product of all the nonzero
entries, with sign $(-1)^{d}\operatorname{sgn}\sigma =-1$. The characteristic polynomial is
$$
x^{d}-\rho ^{b}\lambda _{1}\lambda _{2},...,\lambda _{d}
$$
so its roots are the eigenvalues
$$
\left( \rho ^{b}\prod_{i}\lambda _{i}\right) ^{1/d}\omega
^{k},~k=0,1,\ldots ,d-1.
$$
where the $\omega ^{k}\ $are the $d$th roots of unity. Using the general
theory below, this case occurs when $d$ and $b$ are coprime.
The product $\prod_{i}\lambda _{i}$ of first eigenvalues of the
blocks of $A^{a}$ can be evaluated using the formula above as
$$
\prod_{k=0}^{d-1}\exp (+2\pi ir^{k}a/m)=\exp \left( +2\pi
i(a/m)\sum_{k=0}^{d-1}r^{k}\right) =\exp \left( +2\pi i\frac{a\left(
r^{d}-1\right) }{m\left( r-1\right) }\right) =1
$$
where the last equality uses $r^{p}\operatorname{mod}m=1$ or $m|r^{p}-1$. For the
second eigenvalues replace the explicit $+$ with $-$; the result is the
same. (For $r=1,$ $\sum_{k=0}^{d-1}r^{k}=d$ and the relationship may not
hold.) That is, the eigenvalues of $A^{a}B^{b}$ are the same as those of $%
B^{b}$ for the common case of a single-cycle permutation.
Another simple case is when $b\operatorname{mod}d=0$. This is the case where $W$ is
diagonal, $C_{d}=I_{d}$, and $B^{b}$ is in block diagonal form. The
permutation has only cycles of length 1 (fixed points). The blocks of $B^{b}$
are all $\left( R_{n}^{d}\right) ^{b/d}=R_{n}^{b}$ with eigenvalues $\exp
(\pm 2\pi ib/n)$ and combine with the respective block sof $A^{a}$ so the
eigenvalues of $A^{a}B^{b}$ are the respective products
$$
\exp (\pm 2\pi ir^{k}a/m)\exp (\pm 2\pi ib/n),k=0..d-1
$$
Here both first and second eigenvalues are included, with upper and lower
signs respectively.
In the general case where the permutation has multiple cycles, the
characteristic polynomial factors in a pattern related to the cycle lengths.
Then some eigenvalues have products of only a proper subset of $\lambda _{i}$
and the eigenvalues of $A^{a}B^{b}$ generally will not be the same as those
of $B^{b}$. The general form is $W=D_{A^{a}}D_{\rho ,b}C_{d}^{b}$, where $%
D_{A^{a}}=\operatorname{diag}\left( \lambda _{1},\ldots \lambda _{d}\right) $ and
$$
D_{\rho ,b}=\operatorname{diag}\left( \rho ^{\lfloor b/d\rfloor },\ldots ,[d-(d
\operatorname{mod}b)\,\mathrm{times}],\rho ^{\lfloor b/d\rfloor +1},\ldots ,[d\operatorname{
mod}b~\mathrm{times}]\right) .
$$
The eigenvalues for the product of a diagonal matrix and a permutation
matrix (a PD or monomial matrix) are discussed in Ref. 1. Working this
through for the case here leads to the following prescription. Find the
cycles in the permutation $(1,2,\ldots ,d)^{b}$. There are $s=\gcd (d,b)$
cycles each of length $l=d/s$. For each cycle of length $l$, there is a set
of $l$ first eigenvalues given by
$$
\left( \rho ^{b/s}\prod_{cycle}\lambda _{i}\right) ^{1/l}\omega
_{l}^{k},~k=0,1,\ldots ,l-1.
$$
where the $\prod_{cycle}\lambda _{i}$ means the product of $
\lambda _{i}$ with subscripts that are the $l$\ numbers in the cycle, and $
\omega _{l}=\exp (2\pi i/l)$. As before the second eigenvalues are the
complex conjugates of these.

P.J. Davis, Circulant Matrices, Wiley, 1979, Sec 5.3, p. 166.


Have now got a complete theory including all cases. Not all details are present in the last section. The relationship to permutations is complicated, but these are easily evaluated compared to the matrices or characteristic polynomials. I have checked with Maple for many cases, though there is a large parameter space.
